# Updating multiple documents based on condition

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

My Express API has two main entities:

- Users
- Clients

Each `user` has a list of `clientIds` they are allowed to see.

When a new `client` is added to the system, that `clientId` needs to be added to all `users` who are allowed to see newly added clients.

How would I do the update query in Mongoose, considering that I need to add the new `clientId` to the existing list of `clientIds` for each `user` who has `canSeeNewClients == true`?

```js
User.updateMany(
    // Find all users who can see new clients
    {"canSeeNewClients": true},
    // Add the new clientId to the user's list of clientIds 
    {"$set":{"listOfClientIds": ??? }}
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your `User` model look somthing like this:

```js
{
    "_id": "123",
    "canSeeNewClients": true,
    "clientIds": [
        "2",
        "3"
    ]
}
```

then you can add the `clientId` with an update and `$push`, you can replace `$push` with `$addToSet` to be sure that a `clientId` won't be added twice:

```js
await Users.updateMany(
    { canSeeNewClients: true },
    { $push: { clientIds: clientId } }
);
```

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm! Would there be a way to modify this, so that in addition, it adds the `clientId` to the currently logged in user (the user who created the client), independently of whether or not this user canSeeNewClients? So in your query it would need to be something like: `(canSeeNewClients == true) OR (id = currentUser.id)` ?

Comment: you can do that with `await Users.updateMany(
    { $or: [{ canSeeNewClients: true }, { _id: currentUser.id }] },
    { $push: { clientIds: clientId } }
);`